# Not requesting through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

To send values to php through ajax ,i have created following functions in JS.

```
 function sendDataToServer(url,val)
    {
        var html='';
        html +='<div id="fakeDiv">';
        html +='<form action="'+url+'" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fakefrm">';
        html +='<input type="hidden" name="jsvar" id="jsvar" value="'+val+'"/>';
        html +='</form>';
        html +='</div>';
        $('body').append(html);
        sendAjaxForm($('#fakeDiv'),function(){return true;},
function(){alert('done');$("#fakeDiv").remove();});
    }
```

sendAjaxForm

```
function sendAjaxForm(frm,callbackbefore,callbackdone)
{
    var form = frm;
    form.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        var ajaxReq=$.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                            callbackbefore();
                        }
            });

            ajaxReq.done(function(data){
                callbackdone(data);
            });
    }); // submit done
}
```

Then calling it on the page as

```
sendDataToServer("master.php?action=send_token","23x4dzy009r");
```

But no request is being made , as seen in console..  No any syntax error even recognised . What is wrong in this ??

Comment: Note: You might as well just return the $.ajax promise and avoid the unecessary callbacks. Just use `.then(`succesfunction, failfunction)`

Comment: You add handler for submit event, but did not raise event.

Comment: And i can not understand why you create form? Why you do not send parameters directly?

Comment: You are submitting '#fakeDiv' is a div not form

Comment: it is just a simple example , i need form to send file in another situation @AntonM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is sending request not.
Do changes as per your requirements

```js
function sendDataToServer(url,val)
    {
        var html='';
        html +='<div id="fakeDiv">';
        html +='<form action="'+url+'" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fakefrm">';
        html +='<input type="hidden" name="jsvar" id="jsvar" value="'+val+'"/>';
        html +='</form>';
        html +='</div>';
        $('body').append(html);
        console.log($('#fakefrm'));
        sendAjaxForm($('#fakefrm'),function(){return true;},
function(){alert('done');$("#fakeDiv").remove();});
    }

function sendAjaxForm(frm,callbackbefore,callbackdone)
{
    var form = frm;
    form.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        console.log(formData);
        var ajaxReq=$.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                            callbackbefore();
                        }
            });

            ajaxReq.done(function(data){
                callbackdone(data);
            });
    }); // submit done
    form.submit();
}
sendDataToServer('http://localhost/', 'data');
```

Note : First create handler then submit the form.

Comment: It is most nearest answer what i implemented .. thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have passed `#fakeDiv` as your form, actually it should be `#fakefrm`.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of your culprits:

```
beforeSend: function(){
  callbackbefore();
}
```

You do not return any value from your beforeSend-function, which then is treated as a `false` return value (or actually `undefined`, but that is a [falsey](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/) value). And according to [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> Returning `false` in the `beforeSend` function will cancel the
>   request.

There is no reason to wrap `callbackbefore` in another function. `callbackbefore` already *is* a function so just send it in, without parentheses, as it is:

```
beforesend: callbackbefore
```